# String split lines (unicode?)

Tags: python, string, text

## Question

What is the difference between strings shown down below? How can I split and rejoin them as intended?

## Final goal

I try to extract verses from stanzas. Some text e.g. "one\ntwo\nthree" should be printed at the end as

```
1 one
2 two
3 three
```

Behind the scenes I need every row shown here for further actions - without the number before.

## Status

### Output experiment comparison

I wonder why the string created internally below (see "However...") behaves like expected, while the text shown in "Raw text experiment" below does not.

> learn_drama$ python3 cli.py --print_input --text_input "one\ntwo\nthree"

```
-- Raw text experiment --
one\ntwo\nthree
<class 'str'>
['one\\ntwo\\nthree']
-- End raw text experiment--
-- However... --
one\ntwo\nthree
<class 'str'>
['one', 'two', 'three']
```

### Code/Example

> learn_drama$ cat cli.py

```
"""Console script"""                                                                                                                   
import sys                                                                                                                             
import click                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                       
@click.command()
@click.option("--text_input", help="Type in some text.", default="No text")                                                           
@click.option("--print_input/--no-print_input", help="Prints text input on console.", default=False)                                  
def main(text_input, print_input):
    """Console script"""
    if print_input:
        click.echo("-- Raw text experiment --")
        click.echo(text_input)
        click.echo(type(text_input))
        click.echo(str.splitlines(text_input))
        if text_input == "":
            click.echo("No input given")
        click.echo("-- End raw text experiment--")
        click.echo("-- However... --")
        comparison_string = "one\ntwo\nthree"
        click.echo(text_input)
        click.echo(type(comparison_string))
        click.echo(str.splitlines(comparison_string))
    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())  # pragma: no cover
```

## Why unicode? in question title?

While searching for some hints I often stumbled upon questions and answers being encoding related. I remember that in between I somehow got 'unicode' for `type(some_value_in_between)`.

Comment: Your code is a massively convoluted way to ask a very simple question. Requiring a third-party module to access the command-line arguments is just a useless complication; you could equally just ask *'why is `sys.argv[1] != "one\ntwo\nthree"` when I run `python script.py "one\ntwo\nthree"`?'*

Comment: There is probably a better duplicate but this must have been asked thousands of times. Please search before asking.

Comment: Python 3 does not have a `unicode` type. You must have used Python 2 for one of your experiments.

Comment: A complication is that `"\n"` in the shell simply represents a literal backslash and a letter `n`. People who are unfamiliar with the shell have the weirdest ideas about itse behavior but it's unclear whether that's a factor here.

Comment: @tripleee Thank you for the hint to have an easier question. Maybe my code could be easier, however, click gives me some help with templates to build the bigger program. Regarding the duplicates, I did not find any that really helped me. See my added comment under "Why unicode?" I do not understand how the added link "What does the \newline escape sequence mean in python?" should help me. I know already, that "\n" is a special character.

Comment: Just printing out the value of the command-line argument should reveal that it contains a backslash and an `n`. I can still try to see if I can find a better duplicate.

Comment: This too is rather tangential but contains some useful background: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70519978

Comment: I added another duplicate; that too is somewhat vague but one of the answers actually does a decent job of explaining the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text you receive from the command line contains the two literal characters `\` and `n`. The Python string in your code contains literal newlines which are encoded as `\n` but represent one character (also known as LF, `'\u000a'`, etc).

In some more detail,

```
python -c 'from sys import argv; [print(x) for x in argv[1]]' "foo\nbar\nbaz"
```

at the command line will reveal that the input text contains the characters `f`, `o`, `o`, `\`, `n`, `b` etc.

```
python -c 'for x in "foo\nbar\nbaz": print(x)'
```

similarly shows a *literal* newline between `o` and `b`, etc.

In still other words, `\n` *inside a string in Python source code* represents a newline (except in a "raw" string `r'\n'` where a backslash is always just a literal backslash) but elsewhere, `\n` are just the two printable ASCII characters `\` and `n`.

This is a common FAQ.